# WinHTTP: using proxy with authentication

Tags: c++, proxy, http-authentication, winhttp

guys!
I have to use proxy with authentication in my app where I connect to the server. (MFC app, WinHTTP lib).
There is no problem to use simple proxy without username/pass. But how to specify auth method?

I tried the following, but it didn't work and returned me Error 87 (Incorrect PArameter)
http://username:password@hostname.com

Is it correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct. First of all, password is not allowed to be embedded into the URI. However it is not the source of the problem: to provide WinHTTP with proxy authentication details you are expected to use `WinHttpSetCredentials` with:

> AuthTargets [in]
>
> `WINHTTP_AUTH_TARGET_PROXY` - Credentials are passed to a proxy.